# How to convert a '1:30:20' string to time format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, difference, timedelta

I imported a txt file and this is a result:

```
   Place  Bib    Athlete Name          City State Age Gender FinishTime  \
0      1  120     Runner 1            Bronx    NY  31      M    1:21:40   
1      2  910     Runner 2            Bronx    NY  38      M    1:23:16   
2      3  352     Runner 3         New York    NY  45      M    1:24:28   


  Unnamed: 8  
0        NaN  
1        NaN  
2        NaN
```

I would like to convert the FinishTime string object to a time format. Using
pd.to_datetime(race['FinishTime']) I get ValueError: Given date string not likely a datetime. Any suggestions on how to do this? I would like to do calculation on time like Runner 1 was x% faster than Runner 2. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for convert column to [timedelta](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html).

Then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `Athlete Name` and select values by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). Last get difference of `timedeltas`:

```
df.FinishTime = pd.to_timedelta(df.FinishTime)
df = df.set_index('Athlete Name')
runner1 = df.loc['Runner 1', 'FinishTime']
runner2 = df.loc['Runner 2', 'FinishTime']

print('Runner 1 is {} faster than runner 2.'.format(runner2 - runner1))
Runner 1 is 0 days 00:01:36 faster than runner 2.
```

Answer (score 2):

`to_datetime` can take a format argument to specify what the timestamp looks like:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('1:23:16', format='%H:%M:%S')
Timestamp('1900-01-01 01:23:16')
```

So with your data:

```
pd.to_datetime(race['FinishTime'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Wrong answer, for example for a trail, let's say the winner time is 25 hours: pd.to_datetime('25:23:16', format='%H:%M:%S') -> Error

Comment: What if there is NaN in the column?

Answer (score 0):

Stricly speaking the finish time is not a time but a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object that represents a duration, how long it took to finish the race.

Following code can be used to convert a string to a timedelta and do calculations:

```
from datetime import timedelta

finish_time_1 = '1:23:16'
finish_time_2 = '1:24:28'

hours, minutes, seconds = finish_time_1.split(':')
duration_1 = timedelta(hours=int(hours), minutes=int(minutes), seconds=int(seconds))

hours, minutes, seconds = finish_time_2.split(':')
duration_2 = timedelta(hours=int(hours), minutes=int(minutes), seconds=int(seconds))

print('Runner 1 is {} faster than runner 2'.format(duration_2 - duration_1))
```

The result is: "Runner 1 is 0:01:12 faster than runner 2"

Comment: race['hour'] = race.FinishTime.str.split(':').str[0]
    race['mins'] = race.FinishTime.str.split(':').str[1]
    race['secs'] = race.FinishTime.str.split(':', n=2).str[-1]race['FTime'] = race['hour'] + ':' + race['mins'] + ':' + race['secs']

#convert the string to timedelta
race.FTime = pd.to_timedelta(race.FTime)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up coding it:

```
#not sure if I needed to do this
race['FinishTime']=race.FinishTime.str.rjust(8, fillchar='0')

#split out each component of the string
race['hour'] = race.FinishTime.str.split(':').str[0]
race['mins'] = race.FinishTime.str.split(':').str[1]
race['secs'] = race.FinishTime.str.split(':', n=2).str[-1]

#concat each component into a new column
race['FTime'] = race['hour'] + ':' + race['mins'] + ':' + race['secs']

#convert the string to timedelta
race.FTime = pd.to_timedelta(race.FTime)
```